# Sinch Noise Cancellation

Tags: ios, sinch

I am working on a project for app to app video calling and implemented through Sinch SDK. But the problem is, in video calling there is very much noise even after Noise cancellation is On. Please suggest how to reduce the noise??

Comment: What device are you unsung? Are you inte same room?

Comment: No, from different rooms. And the distance is nearly 200 m.

Comment: What devices are you using? Brand and model, and android version?

Comment: iPhone 6(iOS 10.2.1) and nothing happens either Phone Noise Cancellation is On or Off.

Comment: Speaker phone or regular?

Comment: Problem is with speaker phone

Comment: Hmm, our internal tests works well on those devices. can you mail to support@sinch.com and record the call with your computer mic or something (a recording of the call on our server side wont work to hear what you hear)